# Xamarin Forms - Check from Custom Renderer if control has properties set from XAML

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I have Custom Renderers for some controls (`Button`, `Picker`, `Label`) and there are some common properties, which I have set in the Custom Renderers and in some cases, I want to set different properties, which I have set from XAML. But, because of Custom Renderers, the properties set in XAML are overridden. Is there any way to check in the Custom Renderers, if those properties are set from XAML and to avoid the common behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add check using the `DefaultValue` property on the corresponding bindable property.

For example, following code will assign new value only if the `BackgroundColor` property on the control was not set in XAML, style, or binding.

```
if(Element is Label lbl)
{
    if(lbl.BackgroundColor.Equals(Label.BackgroundColorProperty.DefaultValue))
    {
        lbl.BackgroundColor = newValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Works just the way I want!